# Can I code a "finally" with AngularJS resource version 1.2.3?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code using AngularJS resource:

```
var entityResource = $resource('/api/:et/', {
                            et: $scope.entityType
                     });
entityResource.save(data,
   function (result) {
      // code
      $scope.modal.submitDisabled = false;
   }, function (result) {
      // code
      $scope.modal.submitDisabled = false;
   });
```

Is there something like a finally that I can use so I can put  the code to disable (and my other code) outside of the success and error? Also can I now use .success and .error or do I still have to code as two functions inside () ?

I did notice changes in 1.2.3 but I am not sure if I understand how these apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There Should be a `$promise` property on your `entityResource`. You should be able to set `finally` there.

```
entityResource.$promise['finally'](function(){
  // finally do something
});
```

see [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#The%20Resource%20instances%20and%20collection%20have%20these%20additional%20properties%3a)

**update:** You could do something like this:

```
//Using the promise on your resource.
function success(){/**success*/};
function error(){/**failure*/};
function last(){/**finally*/};
entityResource.save(data,success,error).$promise.finally(last);
```

By using angular's `$q` and `.then` You will invoke a `$digest` cycle. Which will update your view, which is usually fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I code using .finally is that also okay. One more question. How could I add in the success and error. Could I use the . notation for success, error and finally ?

Comment: .finally is ok. But since finally is a keyword it won't work in <=IE8. I would suggest using the promise in the way that I show in the update. I don't think those methods (.error,.success) exist for $resource.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking but in my code I use something more like this: entityResource.save(data,function (result) {}, function (result) {} );   

How would I fit your code into my needs for getting back the data and also using the .save?  Here's what I saw in the release notes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md  Resource.query().$promise.then(callback);  It looks quite different from what you had as you are using a finally but then in the release notes it's using finally for $get but I don't see it for $resource.

Comment: updated answer! Which should work as of 1.2.2 "Always return a resource instance when calling class methods (save) on resources"