# After calling $resource is the digest cycle run so as to redisplay the data in my view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created the following question to ask for some help using $promise for finally with $resource for version 1.2.2 and higher. I'm asking this because as far as I can see it's not even mentioned in the documentation and there are no good examples there :-(

[Previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428527/can-i-code-a-finally-with-angularjs-resource-version-1-2-3)

The answer was:

```
//Using the promise on your resource.
function success(){/**success*/};
function error(){/**failure*/};
function last(){/**finally*/};
entityResource.save(data,success,error).$promise.finally(last);
```

However what confused me was the following statement:

```
"By using angular's $q and .then You will invoke a $digest cycle. 
Which will update your view, which is usually fantastic."
```

Does this mean to say that if I use the code above to call my resource then I won't update the view? What I am currently doing is to update the view manually like this:

```
entityResource.update({ id: entityId }, data,
      function (result) {
         angular.copy(result, $scope.modal.data);
      },error).$promise.finally(last);

         ...
```

Is this the correct way for me to be doing this?

Comment: It will update the view.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I wasn't more clear earlier. I'll try to explain it better...

## What

- `$resource` is a high level abstraction on both `$http` and also `$q`.
- Any callbacks used in `$resource` instance methods that change data-bound values will update the view because a digest cycle will be run.(Yes, to your title question)

### The How

- `$resource` methods will execute your success and error callbacks inside their own success and error callbacks that it sets on the *internally* invoked `$http` methods' promises...

  - eg. `$http(config).then(internalSuccess,internalError)`
- `$resource` takes that value, another promise, and sets the `$promise` property letting you add the `finally` callback if you wish.
- **then** is important internally to `$resource` because the method will be executed by `$rootScope.evalAsync` which in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24evalasync) states that at least one digest cycle will occur

  - [$q source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js) -- The source code has better documentation...:P

All this to say whatever modifications you make to a data-bound `$scope` property within a `then` clause (or a `$resource` callback) will be reflected in the view on it's completion. This is because of angular's implementation of `$q` or moreover `$q`'s implementation of `$rootScope.evalAsync`.

In your particular case, You just need to modify the `$scope` properties with the values from your resource on success. Whether you do that as a shallow copy, or a deep copy (angular.copy) It shouldn't matter. Unless of course your resource instance is on the scope. Then it will be updated automatically. (because that is the abstraction $resource provides)

I hope this explained things well!